# pasting content to a file - NSFileManager

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I want to add contents to file2(file2 already contains content and should not be replaced) from a file1. **copyItemAtPath** throws error as file2 already exists.Is there a way to just add contents to a file instead of replacing existing contents.

```
 if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:logPath2])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logPath2 contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];


if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath: logPath1 toPath:
     logPath2 error: &err])
            NSLog (@"Temp Move successful");
else
    NSLog (@"Temp Move failed  %@",err);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `NSFileManager`, but you can use `-[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:append:]` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOutputStream/outputStreamToFileAtPath:append:)) to achieve this.

Comment: can you edit my code in question with output stream, Bare me i am new to this.

Comment: I've pasted a link to the documentation. Try to use it and if you don't succeed I'll help you further. You won't learn if you ask other people to write the code for you. Create a stream with the method I've pasted, then open it (look at the `NSStream` doc) and use `write:maxLength:` to write data. Then close the stream.